# Linux total disk I/O from already running process

Tags: linux, io

I'm working on a performance tool and I'm interested in the total disk I/O i single process have done since it started. I have the porcess PID and i can easily get the current I/O rate with tools like iotop or sar, but not the total I/O.

Is this even logged in Linux and is there a way to get it?

/Mpresmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the `/proc/<PID>/io` file for specific process

```
 $ sudo cat /proc/1/io

rchar: 144440702940
wchar: 4615239440674
syscr: 156954128
syscw: 173077623
read_bytes: 113700176646
write_bytes: 100325525146
cancelled_write_bytes: 2596581376
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is just what i was looking for. Do you know if there is a similar thing in Solaris?

Comment: I'm not solaris guy at all, but probably there is /proc there maybe there is something similar.